# Rearranging elements of a set of sets

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of sets $S=\{s_{1}, s_{2} \ldots s_{n}\}$ that I want to transform into a different set of sets $T=\{t_{1}, t_{2} \ldots t_{m}\}$, $\forall n,m$, where:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|s_{i}|=\sum_{j=1}^{m}|t_{j}|$,

$\forall i \ne j \ \ s_{i}\cap s_{j} = \emptyset  , \ t_{i}\cap t_{j} = \emptyset$

$|t_{j}|_{j=1}^{m}$ is a given

and $\forall t$, elements are sourced from $\{s_{1}\cup s_{2} \cup \ldots \cup s_n\}$

I need to find a method/algorithm that produces $T$ with minimum dispersion of $s$ elements, ie, I need to keep $s_i$ elements as together as possible in $t_j$, say minimize $\sum_{i,j} [s_{i}\cap t_{j}\neq\emptyset]$ (for which I mean the count of all non empty intersections of elements from $S$ and $T$.)

I've tried to figure this out but currently I am at a loss. Any pointers to literature or a possible approach is most welcome.

TIA, Luis

Comment: I don't understand your measure. We can understand this problem as a similarity of a set partition, where the source partition is given, and the cardinalities the target partition is given. See this question for potential partition similarity measures: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347161/how-to-measure-similarity-of-partitions-partitioning

Comment: Are you sure about the constraint to minimize? Think about the situation that $\left|s_{i}\cap s_{j}\right|\neq0\;\Leftrightarrow\; i=j$
  where there are no duplicate elements.

In this situation there are no preferred elements to assign to the $t_{j}$:

Since $\sum_{i}\left|s_{i}\right|=\sum_{j}\left|t_{j}\right|$
  it is possible to assign any element of $\bigcup_{i}s_{i}$
  exactly once and thus any partition of $\bigcup_{i}s_{i}$
  satisfying the constraints on $\left|t_{j}\right|$
  will minimize the above sum.

Conclusion: I think you may want to define a stricter constraint.

Comment: Thanks guys.  $s_i \cap s_j \neq \emptyset$  does not occur. I changed the question and tried to better clarify the objective function.

Comment: I'm not sure if the maximum weighted bipartite matching solves my problem, I'll have a look.  In the meantime, let me give you a practical example. I have a train $S$ with $n$ passenger cars from which I need to transfer all passengers to another train $T$ with $m$ passenger cars. Passenger cars maximum occupancy is variable but overall the trains maximum occupancy is the same.  How can I assign passengers from $S$ to $T$ so that - as much as possible - passengers travelling together in $S$ (defined as being in the same passenger car) end up together in $T$.

Comment: @Larry B.  I think I can see how the maximum weighted bipartite matching would give me a partition similarity metric. Same for many other methods of partition comparison, like counting pairs, Normalized Mutual Information or Variation of Information, that I am familiar with. The issue is that my problem space is large (hundreds of sets, millions of elements) and an exhaustive search of candidate partitionings is not computationally feasible.

Comment: @LarryB. I can now see why you couldn't understand my measure... seems I can't get the problem properly stated :(. Hopefully it's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have only one set $t$
  and there are duplicate elements in the $s_{i}$: $\left|\cup_{i}s_{i}\right|<\sum\left|s_{i}\right|$
  and $\left|t\right|\overset{!}{=}\sum\left|s_{i}\right|$. Your problem is not well posed in this case, as per the standard definition of a set, $t$ cannot contain any duplicates. You need to rethink your whole situation.

Comment: There are no duplicates. My apologies for the mistake. I have corrected the question.